# Recursive MergeSort translation from C to C#

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, mergesort

I am completely stuck with this recursive implementation of a merge sort due to the .NET requirement that all variables must first be instantiated before being used. My professor wants us to translate C code for MergeSort into C#, using a recursive algorithm. Here is the C code:

```
void doMergeSort(contact **head)
{
    // do not process empty or single-node list
    if (head==NULL || *head == NULL || (*head)->next==NULL)
        return;

    contact *first, *second;

    // split the list in half
    splitList(*head, &first, &second);

    // perform recursive merge sort on both halves
    doMergeSort(&first);
    doMergeSort(&second);

    // Merge both halves back together,
    mergeList(first, second)
}
```

Here is my implementation of it:

```
public static void DoMergeSort(ref LinkNode<T> head)
{
    if (head == null || head.Next == null)
        return;

    LinkNode<T> first = null, second = null;

    SplitList(head, ref first, ref second);

    DoMergeSort(ref first);
    DoMergeSort(ref second);

    head = MergeLists(first, second);
}
```

Now, because of the rules of C#/.NET, I cannot leave out instantiating first and second, but declaring them as null within the function screws up the recursive nature of it. I have been stuck on this problem for multiple days and  and my professor is being little help. Would I be better off trying to translate this into an iterative function, or is there a way I can accomplish this recursively?

My only concern with taking an iterative approach is that it would "break the rules" of the assignment.

Comment: If this is a programming exercise carry on... otherwise just use one of the many inbuilt functions to sort.  i.e. List.Sort or linq OrderBy

Comment: Plus I would recommend not using recursive algorithms when dealing with indefinite recursion depths.  Depending on the depth you can easily run out of stack.  The default stack size in a .NET app is only 1MB.  e.g if you take up 100 bytes with each recursion, the maximum possible iterations would be < 10,000

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but your diagnosis cannot possibly be right. Giving initial values to variables *which are just about to be overwritten* cannot possibly "screw up the recursive nature", whatever that means.  Something else is wrong, and whatever it is, it's in code you've neglected to show us.

Comment: "Now, because of the rules of C#/.NET, I cannot leave out instantiating first and second": If you don't want to initiate a variable before passing it by `ref`, use the `out` keyword instead of the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something about C#, but setting first and second = null should not be a problem since SplitList(...) is supposed to split the list from head (which is not null) into two halves, the first half goes into left, the second half goes into second. Then the recursion occurs with the now non-empty first and then second lists, and each level of recursion creates yet another pair of first and second.

The code doesn't quite follow the C code, you need to check if a list only has one node (the C code checks (*head)->next == NULL to do this). If there's only one node, the function should just return.

Although not a part of your class assignment, there is an iterative version of merge sort for linked lists. It uses a small (26 to 32) array of internal lists. It's faster than the recursive version since it doesn't have to scan sub-lists to split them. Wiki article describes this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I have been staring at this for so long that the way the recursion works in this method was really messed up in my mind